# JAX-RS handle the exception before the automatic POJO mapping

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have this function that works on the POST request and it works only if it recive a JSON in the data field of the HTTP packet.
Then automatically it map every single object into JSON and put it into the array **Persona[] lista**.But if there is a field that dosen't exist into the POJO Persona it gives me an error(Like "500 Internal Server Error"), but i can't handle it in code by using try catch. How can I handle it?

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseClass createPersonaInJSON(Persona[] lista)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: In JAX-RS if your request is syntactically incorrect then server will not accept that request. And untill your request reaches server you will not be able to handle the error . Once your request reaches method createPersonaInJSON  then you can handle any errors or exceptions and return them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are consuming and producing JSON, you are probably using Jackson.

So here are a couple of approaches you may consider (and you can use both together):

### Ignoring unknown JSON properties

Depending on your needs, you could implement a [`ContextResolver`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) for [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and disable the [`FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) deserialization feature, so Jackson won't fail if unknown properties are sent in the JSON payload:

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

### Handling Jackson exceptions

Another option would be implementing [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)s for [`JsonParseException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException.html) and [`JsonMappingException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException.html), so you can handle such exceptions according to your needs:

```java
@Provider
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonParseException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Cannot parse JSON")
                       .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

```java
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Cannot parse JSON")
                       .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

And then register them with a binding priority in your [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class, 1);
        register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class, 1);
    }
}
```

If you are not using a [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass, you can annotate the [`ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)s with [`@Priority`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/Priority.html):

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class JsonParseExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonParseException> {
    ...
}
```

```java
@Provider
@Priority(1)
public class JsonMappingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {
    ...
}
```

This solution is particular useful if you have the [`JacksonFeature`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/jackson/JacksonFeature.html) registered and you want to override the behavior of [`JsonParseExceptionMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonParseExceptionMapper.html) and [`JsonMappingExceptionMapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-providers/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/base/JsonMappingExceptionMapper.html) that come with the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider) module.

Comment: I'm using jersey-server 1.8 and jersey-json 1.8, your code is for Jersey 2.26, can i do a similar thing in 1.8? and how?

Comment: @Pisi The `ContextResolver` approach may work in Jersey 1.x, but I haven't tested.

Comment: By using the ContextResolver it gives me an error, infact in this line of code:    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES); it tells me that there isn't any DeserializationFeature class